# How to do full redirect VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I have a very simple scenario where I want to redirect to a new page but struggling to do this. I have a button:

```
<template>
  <button @click="foobar">FOOBAR</button>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

In the script I have

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  methods: {
    foobar() {
      this.$router.push('/home');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Router is setup as follows

```
import './assets/css/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import Home from './components/Home.vue';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/home",
            component: Home
        }
    ]
});

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app');
```

Although this does work, the button remains on screen alongside the new page. How do I do a full page redirect? I think what I am doing is for a SPA.

Comment: This is expected. You didn't place the button inside a view so it's will be shown in all views. You wouldn't be able to do this on purpose if it worked the other way.  If you need the button to be shown only in / route then write this explicitly.

Comment: Think of `<router-view></router-view>` as being replaced by whatever component is in your `routes` definition matching the current path.  The button being outside of router-view will consequently never be replaced (which can sometimes be desirable, i.e. for header/nav elements)

Comment: I don't understand how you navigate between two independent views then? Is that essentially a different app or something else? There is nothing shared between the two views in this instance..

Comment: You navigate between two independent views with buttons/links just like in any web app.  It sounds like you expect your `/` page to be it's own separate view.  But it can't be separate **and** contain `<router-view>`, but `<router-view>` must also exist somewhere... General solution is for App.vue to just be `<template><router-view/></template>`, and then your routes definition have one component assigned to `/` path, and second component assigned to `/home` path.  Each component can contain a link or button that can call `router.push()` to navigate between each other.